# How to handle records when user is selecting "All" records?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

I have requirement where user wants "All" option is few fields.

**1.Sites** has records around 20 (Includes **All** option)

**2.Cost Centers** which are dependent on **1.Sites** has total records around 540 including all **Sites**. Sites may have different number of **Cost Centers** (Includes **All** option)

**3.Employees** which are dependent on **2.Cost Centers** has total records around 29000. Each **Cost Center** may include different number of Employees. (Includes **All** option)

**4. Processes** Which are independents of all above. It includes records around 20.(Includes **All** option)

Now **Sites**, **Cost Centers**, **Employees** and **Processes** have dropdown with "***All***" along with other options.

How would i design database table. Considering below scenarios

1. User selects following:

**Sites** : Riyadh

**Cost Centers** : MA - Medical

**Employees** : **All**

**Processes** : Travel Request and Authorization

2. User has gone for All in Cost Center

**Sites** : Jeddah

**Cost Centers** : **All**

**Employees** : **All**

**Processes** : **All**

Likewise There are few others combinations. And How user should see inserted records so that He/She can easily navigate to record and update/delete it. Right now i was thinking of inserting single records for option **"All"**. For e.g.

User Selects:

**Sites** : Riyadh

**Cost Centers** : Nursing

**Employees** : **All**

**Processes** : **All**

This will insert just one row in database table.

User has requirement that if he has 200 Employees under selected **Cost Center** and he wants to apply for only 70 **Employees**. He needs to do more work.

How user edit the inserted records afterwards. And How view of all records should be rendered so that editing particular records become easy for user.

Answer (score 0):

You don't model the ALL in your data or you have to deal with people mis-assigning an employee to a cost center named ALL under a site named all. You don't want that!

Sites have cost centers, cost centers have employees, there are processes and (I assume) employees may be assigned to them, thus implying a table that links employees to processes. Only store REAL data.

Then you be smart in your queries so that if the user selects ALL for a given drop-down they get ALL matching records, and inserted data must meet proper referential integrity. A cost center must belong to a valid site. An employee must belong to a cost center and may have one or more processes they are linked to.

but putting in "All" placeholders? You're opening yourself up for a world of hurt managing pseudo-relationships versus real relationships if you go down that route.

Comment: This works fine in static systems. What should happen if a new cost center is created? All the expanded "to ALL" relations should be extended?

Comment: Is there a true "all" relationship to be modelled? It's hard to say from the description as he seems to be discussing users querying - "User selects "All" for this category" etc. To my mind the site and call centers are entity's and the relationships may need to be modelled differently, but is there a call center entity "ALL" that is attached to one or more SITE entities? and if so, then what version of that ALL cost center are we talking about? SITE1's or SITE2's? And what actions are permitted against it? Sorry - I just don't agree with creating psuedo-entities to model complex relations

Comment: Completely agree - no pseudo-instances for an entity. And yes, the formation is all but clear.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton Agreed that only REAL data needs to be inserted. Which is inserting employee with process names. In this case, let say Site is Riyadh, Cost Center is All, (All under Riyadh Site). which has employees around 7000 and i needs 3 processes for each employees. I need to insert 21000 records in this case. Or even User selects All processes which is around 20. So 140000 records needs to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have two relationship between Sites and Cost Centers (I'm narrowing it down only to those two entities). Both are optional and one of them must be defined.

The first relation is (un-problematic) zero to one relationship Site to Cost Center (covering the case that the cost center is known and assigned for the Site).

The second relationship covers the case, that no cost center is assigned and the cost must be "somehow allocated". The "ALL" may mean each cost center (say) receives equal share.

This split in two relationship makes the database design more clean, but it will not address the main problem, which is in querying the relation.

The problem is manifested in **OR condition** in join predicates (chasing both paths) which can lead to sub-optimal performance.

So this is the touchstone of your design, collect the main queries and check how they perform on sample data.

One possible approach to attack performance problems would be to define *materialized views* that expand the ALL relationship to every Cost Center (as proposed by @Michael) and that can be refreshed in case of a new Cost Center definition, so you need not to handle manually such changes.